# Problem with passing functional prop to styled components element. Is that posssible at all?

Tags: styled-components

I try to pass the prop being a function (returning boolean) call to Styled Components with no effect.It looks like there is no length applied at all.

I have also tried syntax where "lenth" is fixed and only its value is function return, but stick to this version as clearer for me. also (props.length) without clear comparision and many other combinations.

That is how my styled element is styled

```js
export const header = {
  cell: styled.th`
    background-color: rgba(188, 107, 63, 0.3);
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align-middle;
    ${props => ((props.length === true) ? 'length: 30%;' : 'length: 13%;')};
  `,
};
```

That is my function that returns desired prop

```js
const isThisFirstOrSecondColumn = x => x === 0 || x === 1;
```

That is how my header.cell component is applied (part only, it's a little longer)

```js
return (
      <tr onClick={handleSort}>
        {headers.map((item, index) => (
          <header.cell
            length={isThisFirstOrSecondColumn(index)}
            key={item}
```

Comment: What is `length`? There's no CSS property with that name. Do you mean `height` or `width`? Plus, you don't need to include the semicolon inside the strings in the ternary operator, since it is already present after the whole line.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at the code too long and have not notice that mistake

Answer (score 1):

`length` is no valid css property and therefore your length prop has no effect. Also you would want only pass the values like this:

```
width: ${props => props.length ? '30%' : '13%'};
```

Otherwise you would have to use

```
${props => props.length ? css`width: 30%;` : css`width: 13%;`}
```

`vertical-align-middle;` is also not valid css. Other than that your code looks okay.

Comment: That was obviously the reason, I looked at that too long - what led to lost ability of noticing simplest things